# How to Stop Django ModelForm From Creating Choices for a Foreign Key

Tags: django, django-forms

I have a Django model with a Foreign key to a table that contains about 50,000 records. I am using the Django forms.ModelForm to create a form. The problem is I only need a small subset of the records from the table the Foreign key points to.

I am able to create that subset of choices in the **init** method. How can I prevent ModelForm from creating that initial set of choices?

I tried using the widgets parameter in the Meta method. But Django debug toolbar indicates the database is still being hit.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The autogenerated `ModelChoiceField` will have its `queryset` initialized to the default. The widget is not where you are supposed to customize the `queryset` property.

Define the `ModelChoiceField` manually, initialize its `queryset` to be empty. Remember to name the `ModelChoiceField` the same as the one that would have been automatically generated, and remember to mention that field in the `fields` tuple. Now you can set the `queryset` from the constructor and avoid the database being hit twice.

If you are lucky (and you probably are, please test though), the `queryset` has not been evaluated during construction, and in that case, defining the `ModelChoiceField` manually is not required.

```
class YourModelForm(ModelForm):
    your_fk_field_name = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=YourModel.objects.none())

    class Meta:
        model = YourModel
        fields = ('your_fk_field_name', .......)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(YourModelForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['your_fk_field_name'].queryset = ....
```

Comment: Thanks. I tested your code. It worked great. One thing to watch out for is in the last line the attribute is "queryset" not "choices".

Comment: You are absolutely right, choices is calculated later from `queryset`, so setting `choices` manually here is redundant at best.