# when trying to open admin page on model obj it never loads

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-admin

i have a project i have been building for a while and i recently noticed an issue.
this is using python 3.6 and Django 1.11

I have the following model

```
class Mail(models.Model):
    """
    This stores all Downloaded Mails.
    They relate To alerts raised by the email checking process.
    """
    # This is for turning column numbers into ordering commands
    ordering = {
        '0': {
            'asc': 'mail_from',
            'desc': '-mail_from'
        },
        '1': {
            'asc': 'subject',
            'desc': '-subject'
        },
        '3': {
            'asc': 'received',
            'desc': '-received'
        }
    }
    mail_id = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=255)
    mail_from = models.EmailField()
    subject = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    message = models.TextField()
    alert = models.ForeignKey(Alert, null=True, blank=True)
    received = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now, db_index=True)
    processed = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    class Meta:
        """
        Mails should be ordered by newest first.
        get_latest_by should be the received property
        """
        get_latest_by = 'received'
        ordering = ['-received']

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        """
        :return: Return string in the format 'Mail_id: subject_text'
        :rtype: str
        """
        return f'<{self.mail_id}: {self.subject}>'
```

i can access and read the mails by using my views. i had been displaying them manually but i decided to switch to using a form to show them. then i noticed my issue. it seems to get stuck in an infinite loop putting this model into a form.

this is the model

```
class MailForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Mail
        fields = ['mail_from', 'subject', 'alert', 'received', 'processed']
```

I then went to open this in the admin site and noticed the same thing going on. i can view the list of mails but when i try to open an individual mail it just keeps loading.

Comment: I expect it's trying to show all the existing Alerts as possible choices for the alert field; if you have many of these it will take a long time to load. Try excluding the alert field.

Comment: wow. that was it. nice spot. any way to get it to stop doing that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to [Daniel Roseman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/104349/daniel-roseman) for noticing the maybe obvious issue is was having.
and i solved it using this answer [How to Stop Django ModelForm From Creating Choices for a Foreign Key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24965328/how-to-stop-django-modelform-from-creating-choices-for-a-foreign-key)

```
class DiplayAlertText(forms.CharField):
    def prepare_value(self, value):
        alert = Alert.objects.get(id=value)
        return alert.message

class MailForm(forms.ModelForm):
    alert = DiplayAlertText()

    class Meta:
        model = Mail
        fields = ['mail_from', 'subject', 'alert', 'received', 'processed']
```